# Node.js Cache Memory Management

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I'm currently looking at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) NPM package to cache data in Node.js. I have also thought about just having a JSON object that stores keys and more JSON objects as values and just using that as a cache.

My question is this. In terms of memory management how would a solution like this work? Obviously Node.js doesn't have unlimited memory, and operating a cache is the lowest priority in terms of what should be freed up if more memory is required.

How could I ensure that it's not caching every single piece of data and not eating up memory if other resources need it?

I don't mind it caching an unlimited amount of data so long as when other resources need memory that it starts to release that memory and takes lower priority.

Comment: why dont you use a singleton object with a cache that timesout after a specific period of time

Comment: @RahulSingh Well I'd prefer not to use timeout. If the server has 8gb of memory and standard operations only take up 2gb lets say why even have it expire or timeout? The only reason is if the system needs more memory. And that still doesn't totally deal with if there is a sudden spike in traffic.

Comment: @charlie Fish you should use redis for memory management, that will handle all your scenarios efficiently,  [take a look at this blog](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-redis-in-memory-key-value-datastore)

Comment: @VikashDahiya And Redis will handle memory management and all that for me?